# code coverage of new lines between 2 commits in ruby

Tags: ruby, git, code-coverage, simplecov

I would like to ensure that all new lines written added are covered by test. Is there a simple way to do an intersection between git diff and simplecov coverage.

http://fredwu.me/post/35625566267/simplecov-test-coverage-for-changed-files-only something like this but with lines granularity instead of files

Comment: HoundCI runs rubocop on your commits. It's just rubocop, but anyway you can check their code (it's open source) and get hints.

Answer (score 3):

For *git* diffs, there is a tool named [diff-cover](https://github.com/Bachmann1234/diff-cover), which can check coverage. It takes Cobertura XML coverage reports and compares with the output of `git diff`. It then reports coverage information for lines in the diff.

With an xml file produced by [simplecov-cobertura](https://rubygems.org/gems/simplecov-cobertura/versions/1.0.2), you can use this command to check the coverage of your changes compared to the `master` branch:

```
$ diff-cover coverage.xml
```